# Easy way to access individual cost terms?

Tags: drake

Let say we call prog.AddCost(...) multiple times and have a triple term cost:

cost(x) = a(x) + b(x) + c(x)

How do we easily access an individual cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `AddCost` returns a binding, which can be evaluated directly, for instance via [`EvalBinding`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_mathematical_program_result.html#a5477c6d7b8af6a3be55e58d0d5e2d768) in `MathematicalProgramResult`.